# Spring Boot 2.0.0.M4 breaks http basic auth in application.yml

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

Spring Boot 1.5.6.RELEASE respected the basic-auth username and password as specified in my application.yml below.

I have upgraded to 2.0.0.M4 and now the application always starts with the default 'user' and randomly generated password.   Basically the settings below are always completely ignored.

I saw some changes in the release note/doc specific to simplifying actuator security enabled/disabled.  I didn't see anything specific to this.

Any ideas?

From my application.yml

```
security:
  basic:
    enabled: true
    realm: some-service
  user:
    name: example_user
    password: example_password
```

---

Update:

I've confirmed this functionality was just plainly taken out starting with Spring Boot 2.0.0.M4

In the appendices:

All the security.basic.* family of stuff is missing here from the M4 reference:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.0.M4/reference/html/common-application-properties.html

But appears here in the M3 reference:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.0.M3/reference/html/common-application-properties.html

I was able to temporarily downgrade to M3 to restore the previous functionality but would still appreciate some guidance on what replaced it.   I just need a single hardcoded basic-auth user for this scenario.   I'm aware I could use object configurations to do a much more complicated setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit 2018-01-31:**

The ability to auto-configure a single user has been restored (via the `spring.security.user` configuration keys) starting with Spring Boot 2.0.0-RC1 ([source](https://spring.io/blog/2018/01/31/spring-boot-2-0-0-rc1-available-now)).

**Original answer:**

The Spring Boot `security.*` properties have been deprecated starting with Spring Boot 2.0.0-M4. You can read about this in the  [Release Notes](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.0.0-M4-Release-Notes):

> Security auto-configuration has been completely revisited: developers should read [the companion blog post](https://spring.io/blog/2017/09/15/security-changes-in-spring-boot-2-0-m4) and refer to the [Spring Boot 2.0 Security wiki page](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-Security-2.0) for more details about the change.

In order to restore the basic auth functionality you can register a custom `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`, like this:

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public InMemoryUserDetailsManager inMemoryUserDetailsManager() {
        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(
                User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder().username("user").password("password")
                        .authorities("ROLE_USER").build(),
                User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder().username("admin").password("admin")
                        .authorities("ROLE_ACTUATOR", "ROLE_USER").build());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .requestMatchers(EndpointRequest.to("health", "info")).permitAll()
                .requestMatchers(EndpointRequest.toAnyEndpoint()).hasRole("ACTUATOR")
                .requestMatchers(StaticResourceRequest.toCommonLocations()).permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/**").hasRole("USER")
                .and()
            .cors()
                .and()
            .httpBasic();
    }

}
```

(This will also configure basic auth for the Actuator endpoints)

If you additionally need to read the username and password from a `.properties` file, you can simply inject the values using the `@Value` annotation.